# Deploy on Windows server with gitlab webhooks

Tags: git, coldfusion, gitlab, webhooks

I want do deploy a webapplication (coldfusion) on a windows machine using gitlab and webhooks, so to be able to push changes to the server automatically,
but it seems that existing solutions are 99% dedicated to linux deploy.

I've already set up manual deployment with git:
    1. clone repository on target machine
    2. each time, connect and pull changes but of course is not automatic at all.

I strictly need a process I can set-up on a windows server.

I've found some reference about using openssh for the task, but I'd prefer a simpler mechanism.

I've also checked the Kudu project https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu but it seems to be a work in progress and not easilly usable product.

Is there anything existing I can use for the task?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

**UPDATE**

Just to be more specific, I need something to automatically deploy changes pulled from a GIT repository, not to merge files, or sync folders.

Ideally, I need something able to respond to gitlab webhooks and trigger a pull from the git repository.

Comment: We use BeyondCompare.

Comment: BeyondCompare as far as I understand is for diff and merge, not for deploy. I need something able to automatically pull changes from a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) is the way to go. It's being used in Azure web services and is being actively maintained, check out the [GitHub activity graph](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/graphs/contributors). It's been around for years and has matured. Also, since it's now a part of Azure I don't see it going anywhere.